# Is there any array function to make array value as key and other value as value of that key?

Tags: php

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'entity_name' => 'single_pdct_prc',
    'entity_value' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'entity_name' => 'ttl_pdct_prc',
    'entity_value' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'entity_name' => 'sub_ttl',
    'entity_value' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `array_flip`? Is the code you posted the input or the expected output? More information and a [mcve] is needed. Thank you.

Comment: @ggorlen
At final I need this result
array ( 'single_pdct_prc' => '1', 'ttl_pdct_prc' => '1', 'sub_ttl' =>'1')

Answer (score 2):

The [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function does exactly what you are looking for.

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'entity_name' => 'single_pdct_prc',
    'entity_value' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'entity_name' => 'ttl_pdct_prc',
    'entity_value' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'entity_name' => 'sub_ttl',
    'entity_value' => '1',
  ),
);

$result = array_column($arr, 'entity_value','entity_name');
//$result: array(3) { ["single_pdct_prc"]=> string(1) "1" ["ttl_pdct_prc"]=> string(1) "1" ["sub_ttl"]=> string(1) "1" }
```